# How to join group item of Linq Query Group By?

Tags: wpf, linq, group-by

I have three tables that are related.

```
    Letter(Id,Name)

    SendLetter(Id,LetterId)

    ReciveLetter(Id,SendLetterId,Type,User)
```

I want to get records of ReciveLetter that Group By `SenLetterId` & `Type`.

I use this query.

```
    var dashbord = from d in db.ReceiveLetter
                            where (d.SendLetter.LetterId == LetterId)
                            group d by new { d.SendLetter, d.SendType } into g
                            select new Items{ ...... };
```

It is group Items by SendLetterId and Type. I want to select join of UserName for each grouped item.

for example:

```
    SendLetter:
    1   1   
    2   1      

    ReciveLetter:
    1   1    Type1   A
    1   1    Type1   B
    1   1    Type2   C
    1   2    Type1   D
    1   2    Type1   E

    Result:
    1    1   Type1  A,B
    1    1   Type2  C
    2    1   Type1  D,E
```

Comment: Select join of Username? You mean you want to get the Username from each group?

Comment: I want join all Username of each group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what `Item` looks like and not knowing what type of LINQ you use I can give you a general approach that should work with linq-to-sql and entity framework.

```
var query = from d in db.ReceiveLetter
                where (d.SendLetter.LetterId == LetterId)
                group d by new { d.SendLetter, d.SendType } into g
                select new { g.Key.Sendletter,
                             g.Key.SendType, 
                             Users = g.Select(x => x.Name)
                           };

var dashboard = query.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new Item { x.SendLetter.Id,
                                        x.SendLetter.LetterId,
                                        x.SendType,
                                        Names = string.Join(", ", x.Users)
                                      });
```

`AsEnumerable()` switches the execution to linq-to-objects in order to execute the `string.Join`.

Answer (score 0):

I try something like this (this may be not so optimized):

```
var q=(..//
).GroupBy(x=>new {x.SentLetterType, x.Type});

foreach(var group in q)
{
  foreach(var result in group)
  {
   string sUsername+=result.Username+",";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes can it, but i want to do it without loop. Can it in query?

Comment: Yes, you do it in query, although technically it is still a loop. `.ToEnumerable().ForEach(x => x.DoSomething())`